# .htaccess wildcard redirect from parked domain?

Tags: .htaccess, wildcard

I have two domains pointing to my site, for example; http://some-long-domain.co.uk and http://short.co - I want to be able to share URLs like http://short.co/x/ic5rai, while redirecting all traffic to the www. version of the main domain, and keeping the path on the URL.

To complicate matters, I don't want to touch versions of the domain with a subdomain that I use for development (local. and staging.).

E.g.;

- http://short.co/x/ic5rai -> http://www.some-long-domain.co.uk/x/ic5rai
- http://www.short.co/x/ic5rai -> http://www.some-long-domain.co.uk/x/ic5rai
- http://some-long-domain.co.uk/x/ic5rai -> http://www.some-long-domain.co.uk/x/ic5rai
- http://local.some-long-domain.co.uk/x/ic5rai -> http://local.some-long-domain.co.uk/x/ic5rai
- http://staging.some-long-domain.co.uk/x/ic5rai -> http://staging.some-long-domain.co.uk/x/ic5rai

Current re-write rules look like the following, and work for the latter point (local/staging), but not for anything else. What am I doing wrong?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.some-long-domain.co.uk$ [NC]        
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^local.some-long-domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^staging.some-long-domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^short.co$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.short.co$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.some-long-domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```